# TypeError: 'Win32Window' object is not iterable

Tags: python, pyautogui

I'm programming the following task.

> Automatically click multiple checkboxes.

> When the 'A' pop-up window appears when you click the checkbox, press the 'Enter' key 3 times.

> When the 'B' image appears when you click the checkbox, press the 'Enter' key twice.

> If nothing appears after clicking the checkbox, continue.

> Repeat the above process until all checkboxes are clicked.

However, task A did not solve the problem.

Here is the code I made:

```
import pyautogui
import PIL

pyautogui.sleep(2)

pyautogui.locateAllOnScreen("checkbox.png") 


for i in pyautogui.locateAllOnScreen("checkbox.png"):
    print(i)
    pyautogui.click(i, duration=0.25)
    pyautogui.sleep(1)
    for w in pyautogui.getActiveWindow():
        print(w)
        if w == pyautogui.getWindowsWithTitle("A"):
            pyautogui.press("enter", presses=3)
        else:
            print("not found")
```

When I run the above code, I get the following error:

```
C:\project\a_>c:/python39-32/python.exe c:/project/a_/experi.py
Box(left=152, top=259, width=17, height=15)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\project\a_\experi.py", line 13, in <module>
    for w in pyautogui.getActiveWindow():
TypeError: 'Win32Window' object is not iterable
```

Comment: `pyautogui.getActiveWindow()` returns a single object.  Why are you trying to iterate over a single object?

Comment: What exactly do you want `for w in pyautogui.getActiveWindow()` to do? There's only one active window, so there's nothing to loop over